# Openpyxl observing the max_row of a sheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl, observer-pattern, observers

Is it possible to observe the max row of a sheet for changes?  I have some functions I'd like to run everytime that value is updated (they would be the observers).

Does openpyxl support that?

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('yourFile.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

initial_max_value = ws.max_row

while ws.max_row == inital_max_value:
  THE 
   CODE 
   YOU 
  WANT TO WATCH

  Else:
  Print ('Max Value changed by ' + inital_max_value - ws.max_row
```